# Writing a SQL statement based on the values selected in a checkboxlist

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have two checkbox lists, one for a division and one for a course. One division can have many courses so what I want to do is have my user select whichever divisions they want as there are only 10 then display the courses in another checkbox list which are offered by the divisions that have been selected.

Precursor info:

```
private DataTable GetData(string query)
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseName"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = query;

                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

                    using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                    {
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        return dt;

                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

This is my code where I bind the data to the `Divisions` checkbox list:

```
protected void GetDiv()
{
    string query = " Select distinct uio.OFFERING_ORGANISATION as [Div], ou.FES_FULL_NAME as [Division] From UNIT_INSTANCE_OCCURRENCES uio " +
                   " inner join ORGANISATION_UNITS ou on uio.OFFERING_ORGANISATION = ou.ORGANISATION_CODE " +
                   " inner join REPORTYEARS ry on uio.CALOCC_OCCURRENCE_CODE = ry.CAL_OCC " +
                   " Where ry.REPORT_YEAR = (select DETAILS from EF_REFERENCE_DATA Where REC_TYPE = 'Rep_Year') and uio.OFFERING_ORGANISATION is not null Order By [Division] ";

    cbDivSelect.DataSource = GetData(query);
    cbDivSelect.DataTextField = "DIVISION";
    cbDivSelect.DataValueField = "DIV";
    cbDivSelect.DataBind();
}
```

I use this to get a list of the divisions selected:

```
protected void cbDivSelect_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        foreach (ListItem item in cbDivSelect.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected) Divisions.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

and then this to display the Courses:

```
protected void GetCourse()
    {
        foreach(ListItem item in Divisions)
        {
            string GetCourses = "SELECT distinct Course_Code,Course_Code + ' - ' + Marketing_Title AS COURSE, Parent FROM e_prospectus WHERE (Div = '" + item.Value.ToString() + "') ORDER BY Course_Code";
            cbCourseSelect.DataSource = GetData(GetCourses);
            cbCourseSelect.DataTextField = "COURSE";
            cbCourseSelect.DataValueField = "Course_Code";
            cbCourseSelect.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Now currently it only displays the lowest course in the list which has been selected, i'm assuming because i keep changing the data source and it doesn't accumulate but is there any way i can change my code to accommodate what i want? thanks

Comment: please use parameterised queries / stored procedures. Don't build up queries using string concatenation - you leave yourself vulnerable to unexpected syntax errors and, much more importantly, SQL injection attacks.

Comment: `GetData(GetCourses)` returns a list assume? In that case I would just create one list to use as  `DataSource` and `AddRange()` the result of `GetData()` to it. Best to use a `BindingList` as that should take care of updating the binding.

Comment: I am fully aware of parameterised queries i just prefer to build my queries up as strings then add them in as parameters

Comment: GetData returns a datatable, sorry ill add extra code on now, my bad

Comment: Well, same difference :) Create one DataTable as DataSource and Merge the results of GetData into it

Comment: @ReeceHewitson "i just prefer to build my queries up as strings". You may prefer it, but it's well known to be very insecure. If you do this in a real-life application there is a very high chance your application will get hacked. If you don't understand the risks of SQL injection please google it. If you wrote code like this in my team it would be rejected and never be allowed into a live environment. I see from your profile you're a college student so please just take this as friendly advice :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one `DataTable` as `DataSource` and `Merge()` the results of `GetData()` into it.

This would build the whole set in memory. Depending how many Courses you expect using FakeisMe approach of building one query to get all courses out of the database at once might be a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
        string divisions = string.empty ; 
     foreach(ListItem item in Divisions)
            {
           divisions  = divisions  + item.Value.tostring() + ",";
            }

    if (divisions != string.empty)
  { 
    divisions = divisions.Remove(divisions.Length -1, 1)
     string GetCourses = "SELECT distinct Course_Code,Course_Code + ' - ' + Marketing_Title AS COURSE, Parent FROM e_prospectus 
    WHERE (Div in (" + divisions + ")) ORDER BY Course_Code";
                cbCourseSelect.DataSource = GetData(GetCourses);
                cbCourseSelect.DataTextField = "COURSE";
                cbCourseSelect.DataValueField = "Course_Code";
                cbCourseSelect.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Wont this leave a comma which will provide incorrect syntax for the last division?